# For what reason this function is recursive primitive?

Tags: computability, primitive-recursion

Let $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\ \ P(n)$ a primitive recursive predicate such that $\neg P(n)$ for a finite number of values of $n$.

Why this function:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if there are at least $x$ numbers $n$ such that $P(n)$}\\
\uparrow & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

is a recursive primitive function?

**This is my reasoning, could you check whether it is correct?**

If $\neg P(n)$ for a finite numbers of $n$ (let the set of these numbers be $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ where $|A|< \infty$), then $P(n)$ will be defined for $\mathbb{N}−A^c$ numbers, that is for $\infty$ numbers. Then "if there are at least $x$ numbers $n$ such that $P(n)$" will always be true and for this reason $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: All primitive recursive functions are total.

Comment: Your function is just the constant 1 function.

Comment: Why it is just the constant 1 function?

Comment: That's a question for you...

Comment: If I knew the answer, I wouldn't have asked it here. Why it is the constant 1 function?

Comment: Yuval Filmus already gave you a huge hint. Please do the rest yourself, it's trivial.

Comment: This is my reasoning, could you check whether it is correct? If $\neg P(n)$ for a finite numbers of $n$ (let the set of these numbers be $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ where $|A| < \infty$), then $P(n)$ will be defined for $\mathbb{N} - A^c$ numbers, that is for $\infty$ numbers. Then "if there are at least x numbers n such that P(n)" will always be true and for this reason f(x) = 1.

Comment: Please don't delete your question after you've already received an answer.  That is often considered rude.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of questions and answers that will be useful to others in the future, so deleting your question gets in the way of that.

Comment: The reasoning is correct. (If there is more than one person in a comment section for your post and you want one of them to get a notification about your comment, type @<UserName>. E.g in my case type @Dmitry. Otherwise, we don’t receive any notification. There are some cases when it’s not necessary, but it’s safer to always use it)